# target xml is splitting automatically in informatica on based on Primary key

Tags: xml, informatica

I need to generate only one xml target . but as soon as I am getting new PK (as PK should be unique) , Informatica automatically creating new xml  file for new PK .

And If I change my PK logic (non- unique) , so I am not getting full data , many rows are getting rejected .

I am not using any Transaction control or any logic for splitting.

Is there any property ,which I need  to set ?

Thanks & regards,

Shruti

Comment: Something doesn't make sense regarding the format of your xml target i.e. your top level node should be a single set of tags with everything else as child nodes wrapped within it. It sounds like instead you have a series of child nodes with no wrapper parent node and this would result in xml that any parser would identify as invalid. If you add this extra layer in your target definition, the issue should be resolved (of course it will mean a design rethink at all interfaces for you)

Comment: It would help to see how your mapping looks like. If you're talking about the XPK / XFK columns that get added by PowerCenter: These are internal columns that won't appear in your XML. They are only used by PowerCenter to determine the hierarchy of your XML (parent / child relationships). So if you're using a different XPK for every row, I think you will end up with multiple XML files.